# How to apply color to a Pie Chart slice from Google Charts API

Tags: google-visualization

Hi I'm trying to apply color's in the slices of my pie chart. I'm using Google Charts API.

Here you got all the pie chart information: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

And here is is a shortcut about what I'm talking:

> slices    Array of objects, or object with nested objects {}   An array of
>   objects, each describing the format of the corresponding slice in the
>   pie. To use default values for a slice, specify an empty object {}. If
>   a slice or a value is not specified, the global value will be used.
>   Each object supports the following properties:
>
> color - The color to use for this slice. Specify a valid HTML color
>   string. textStyle - Overrides the global pieSliceTextSlice for this
>   slice. You can specify either an array of objects, each of which
>   applies to the slice in the order given, or you can specify an object
>   where each child has a numeric key indicating which slice it applies
>   to. For example, the following two declarations are identical, and
>   declare the first slice as black and the fourth as red:
>
> slices: [{color: 'black', {}, {}, {color: 'red'}] 
>   slices: {0: {color: 'black'}, 3: {color: 'red'}}

Don't know where I should put this code, here's the playground: https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#pie_chart

This is my attemp(which does not work)

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work', 11],
    ['Eat', 2],
    ['Commute', 2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep', 7]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data, {title:"So, how was your day?", slices: [{color: 'black', {color: 'blue'}, {color: 'green'}, {color: 'red'}, {color: 'white'}]});
}
​
```

Thanks for your time.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

**EDIT:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
          slices: {0: {color: '#006EFF'}, 1:{color: '#00FF08'}, 2:{color: 'blue'}, 3: {color: 'red'}, 4:{color: 'grey'}}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note: I used

```
slices: {0: {color: '#006EFF'}, 1:{color: '#00FF08'}, 2:{color: 'blue'}, 3: {color: 'red'}, 4:{color: 'grey'}}
```

instead

```
slices: [{color: 'black', {}, {}, {color: 'red'}]
```

See you.

Comment: Hi guys, I think that the problem is because the playground. I tested this code(see the edited post) in my VPS and it worked fine.

Answer (score 38):

You can use following to change default color of pie chart slices:

```
var options = {
  width: 400,
  height: 240,
  title: 'Toppings I Like On My Pizza',
  colors: ['#e0440e', '#e6693e', '#ec8f6e', '#f3b49f', '#f6c7b6']
};
```